# How to create icons on the desktop of ubuntu?

Tags: installation, launcher, icons, unzip

For example if I download a program, unzip it and how do I install it and make it appear the icon on the launcher or desktop?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but 99% of the time you would be better off using the Software Centre (or apt-get if you're a CLI-warrior) to install software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's already installed do the following:

Open the HUD by pressing Alt+F2 and type the name of the program you want on the desktop.

When its icon appears, click and hold the mouse on it and drag it to an empty part of the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

The download should offer install. To put an icon on the desktop or elsewhere:

Open Dash Home, reduce to show some desktop, find the app, click and drag the icon. That's it!